# How should the .htaccess look like for Symfony routing

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony

I've been trying some of Symfony's components and it's going relatively well. I figured out, after a bunch of Googling, that I needed to change the .htaccess file into at least this in order for it to work:

```
<IfDefine APACHE2>
    AcceptPathInfo on
</IfDefine>
<Files "index.php">
    Options +Includes
    SetOutputFilter INCLUDES
    AcceptPathInfo On
</Files>
```

However now whenever I want to do a `header()` call or have an img/script/stylesheet tag I need to have a ../ before I enter the path. And when I have a variablename (i.e. path looks like this: `index.php/article/32` for instance) I need ../../ before I enter he rest of the path into the src or href.
Have I set up my .htaccess file wrong or is there something else I need to do?

So an img tag would be like this:

```
<img href="../PATH_TO_IMAGE">
```

for when there is no placeholder and like this:

```
<img href="../../PATH_TO_IMAGE">
```

for when there is a variable in the placeholder thingy.

Because I suspect it should not be this way.

My routing looks like this:

```
$routes = new RouteCollection();
$routes->add('loginuser', new Route('/login', array('controller' => 'registeruser', 'permission' => Permissions::$public)));
```

(I followed a tutorial on some website, sadly I can't seem to find it right now)

EDIT: I'm only using the Routing component and the Http Foundation component.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: use the [asset](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/asset/introduction.html) component to manages URL generation of the image, ant the router component to generate path of some route. are you using the full stack framework, or only some selected component?

Comment: @Federico I'm using the routing and http foundation components. So I have to use the asset component for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this by adding the Asset component from Symfony and creating a PathPackage that start by pointing to the root and further on into the web folder.

```
$package = new PathPackage('/ENTER_FURTHER_PATH_HERE/', new EmptyVersionStrategy());

echo '<img src="'. $package->getUrl('Images/icon.png') . '">';
echo '<a href="' . $package->getUrl('index.php/WHATEVER') . '">Link name</a>';
echo '<a href="' . $package->getUrl('index.php') . '">Home</a>';
echo '<script src="'. $package->getUrl('Scripts/JAVASCRIPT_NAME') .'"></script>';
echo '<link src="'. $package->getUrl('CSS/STYLESHEET_NAME') .'">';
```

(you could also skip the PathPackage and do like this as it's not strictly necessary)

```
echo '<a href="/ENTER_FURTHER_PATH_HERE/index.php">Home</a>;
```

Anyway, that's how I solved it. if anyone knows any better way, feel free to tell me. It would be very appreciated.